# Get requests callback Python

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, jupyter-notebook, python-requests

I need to get a code from an authorization get requests. I have this:

```py
r = requests.get(endpoint_auth,params=query_params)
url=r.url
webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)
```

When I authorize myself I get redirected to the redirect url I specified in the app settings. But I don't get the response with the authorization code which I need later for doing anything. How can I get a callback for that?

How would I do that ?

Comment: Spotify oAuth endpoints are `https://accounts.spotify.com/api/...`  - `api.spotify.com/v1` is for end-user APIs (aka Spotify Web APIs), these are callable with the acquired token.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Jupyter above.

I switched to Visual Studio Code and was able to resolve the core issue with Flask.